Why do Surface codes generate so much measurement data?
I read in the Sparse Blossom paper: "A surface code superconducting quantum computer with a million physical qubits will generate
measurement data at a rate of around 1 terabit per second".
I was wondering about the source/measurement workflow that would lead to so much data creation?

In a surface code, half the qubits are measurement qubits used to measure the stabilizers. In a superconducting chip you can run a surface code cycle, measuring all the stabilizers, in less than a microsecond. Note you want to measure as fast as possible to catch errors before they accumulate into logical errors.
One million qubits times one million cycles per second times a measure qubit density of one half equals half a trillion measurements per second. 0.5 terabits per second.

To put 500 Gb/s into perspective, a common interface for GPUs in use for the last several years, PCIe 4.0 x16, can transfer about 256 Gb/s. There are two other facts that are quite nice as well: 1) You don't have to do all your decoding in one place 2) The syndrome is pretty compressible: For a surface code under circuit noise of 10^3, the syndrome flip rate is about 1%, corresponding to about 1/10-th of a bit of entropy per syndrome bit. So a good compression algorithm can get about a factor of 10x compression ratio!

(This is also an indication that surface code is not a very good code: Error correction, in a sense, is compression of the distribution of errors, so a syndrome with low entropy per bit is indicative that your code is not performing very well. Of course, this totally neglects other considerations like layout and logical operations)

Another way to tell that the surface code is verbose with its data, which I know @chrispattison is also familiar with, is to notice that it gives a huge amount of soft information. You can pretty accurately estimate how likely it is that a surface code has failed. Activating that information, by concatenating even an error detecting code on top of the surface code, substantially improves its efficiency at correcting errors.
